# Why isn't $\ i $ equal to $\ 0 $

Tags: complex-numbers

$\ e^{i\pi}= -1$

$\ e^{2i\pi}= 1$

Taking $\ ln$  on both sides :

$\ {2i\pi}= 0$

Since $\ 2 {\pi}$ is a constant. Therefore, $\ i$  must be equal to $\ 0$

But we know, that $\ i= {\sqrt{-1}} $. Then where am i going wrong?

Comment: The short version is that logarithm-taking is multi-valued in the complex domain. Quite different from what you're used to in the "real world". So $e^z = 1$ has an infinite number of distinct complex solutions, and $0$ is just one solution.

Comment: The complex logarithm is multivalued: very different from the real one.

Comment: Ohk got it.Thank you @Deepak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex logarithm is a multivalued function, this means that for every complex number $z\neq 0$, $\log z$ is defined up to a constant, which is exactly $2\pi i$; (Remember that every $z\neq 0$ can be write as $z=e^w$)
infact: $\log z= \log |z| + i\arg z$. $\text{   }$$\arg z$ is a periodic function, for every turn around the origin $\arg $ increase by $2\pi$.

This is the reason why when you use the complex logarithm you have to choose a branch of it where it is well defined, that is defined uniquely, that is a domain where $\log z$ become a single-value function.

You can easily see that $1=e^{i\pi 0}$ and $e^{2\pi i}$ always belong to different branch cuts.

Answer (score 2):

It may be consolotary for you (and instructive for all of us) to know that even the famous J. Bernoulli is credited (re. (1)) to have
fallen in the same trap, by *"demonstrating"* that  $\ln ( - z) = \ln (z)$, through the following passages
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \ln \left( {\left( { - z} \right)^{\,2} } \right) = \ln \left( {z^{\,2} } \right) \\ 
 \ln \left( { - z} \right) + \ln \left( { - z} \right) = \ln \left( z \right) + \ln \left( z \right) \\ 
 2\ln \left( { - z} \right) = 2\ln \left( z \right) \\ 
 \ln \left( { - z} \right) = \ln \left( z \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

The pitfall is in the passage from 2nd to 3rd line, where using the multivalued
logarithm ($ {\rm Ln}$) we have
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 {\rm Ln}\left( z \right) = \ln \left| z \right| + i\,{\rm Arg}(z) = \ln \left| z \right| + i\arg (z) + i\,2k\pi  \\ 
 {\rm Ln}\left( { - z} \right) = \ln \left| { - z} \right| + i\arg ( - z) + i\,2k\pi  = \ln \left| z \right| + i\arg (z) + i\,\left( {2k + 1} \right)\pi  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
and clearly the two sets do not have any value in common, as already remarked in *Gianluca*'s answer.

'   ----------------
(1) " Theory of analytic functions" - A.I. Markuševič